# Remove bootstrap carousel gradient

Tags: html, css, carousel

guys im trying to remove the gradient caused by the `left carousel-control`.

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true">/span>

<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add this: `style="background:red !important"`

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="background:red !important">
```

to remove complete     `background: none;`

Comment: I put red but you can choose your color ;)

Comment: Thanks alot! It worked. Is there a way for me to change the color of the chevron arrows? Because when i changed the background to white, the arrows are hard to see.

Comment: create a style: .glyphicon {color:blue !important;} or insert a style style="color:blue !important"

Comment: Hi i tried using both of the styles to change the color of the chevron arrows but does not work. Is there another way?

Comment: Hi, i've figured out the way to change the color of the arrow already. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, how do i mark the question as answered? I am not really sure with using this website.

Answer (score 1):

When experimenting, I found removing the class `left` from `<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">` seemed to remove the gradient.

It should look like this once removed - `<a class="carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">`

The same can be done for the right carousel control too, just remove the `right` class.

Comment: This displays the one on top of the other. When I add class=col-md-offset-10 to the "next" slider element, they render more or less ok. Bit hackey though...

Answer (score 0):

When the class left is remove, the gradient color will be removed too. But when the class right is remove the alignment of the button will for the prev and next is affected.